# Example of function where one-sided directionaly derivative does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

One can show that for convex functions $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ the so-called one-sided directional derivative exists:

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a point where $f$ is finite. Then this derivative is given as the following if the finite or infinite limit

$$
Df(x_0,v) := \lim_{h^{+} \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+ hv) - f(x_{0})}{h}
$$

exists. It's quite a different notion to a "normal" derivative since we also allow infinite limits. An example of this is $f(x) = -\sqrt{x}$ for $x \ge 0$ where we can see that:

$$
Df(0,1) = \lim_{h^{+} \to 0} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} = -\infty
$$

I was wondering what a good example is of a (continuous?) function where the one-sided directional derivative does not exist (thus also not convex). I guess I could construct some highly non-continuous function like

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x,  & \text{ if } \left \lceil{1/x}\right \rceil \mod 2 = 0\\
-x, & \text{ else.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: *where the one-sided directional derivative does not exist* -- There is more than one directional derivative, so what do you mean by "**the** one-sided . . ."? More specifically, are you looking for an example in which at a specified point (a) at least one directional derivative doesn't exist, or (b) more than one directional derivative doesn't exist, or (c) infinitely many directional derivatives don't exist, or (d) uncountably many directional derivatives don't exist, or (e) densely many directional derivatives don't exist, or (f) every directional derivative doesn't exist, . . . ?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I guess I was looking for a continuous function where (a) because the one-sided directional derivative needs to be defined for all directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example could be $f(x)= \begin{cases} x \sin \frac{1}{x}, & x \ne0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$.